# NullPointerException when drawing a view

Tags: android

I have a problem that I am getting a NullPointer Exception when drawing a custom View on the screen, but don't know where the actual problem occurs, and unable to find the thing which is missing for generating the Exception.

So Please suggest me for the right solution regarding this subject.

**Error Stack:**

```
   02-24 14:18:46.181: E/AndroidRuntime(7547): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-24 14:18:46.181: E/AndroidRuntime(7547): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-24 14:18:46.181: E/AndroidRuntime(7547):     at android.graphics.Canvas.throwIfRecycled(Canvas.java:954)
02-24 14:18:46.181: E/AndroidRuntime(7547):     at android.graphics.Canvas.drawBitmap(Canvas.java:980)
02-24 14:18:46.181: E/AndroidRuntime(7547):     at com.TestFace.FaceDetect.DrawView.onDraw(DrawView.java:89)
02-24 14:18:46.181: E/AndroidRuntime(7547):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6740)
02-24 14:18:46.181: E/AndroidRuntime(7547):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1640)
02-24 14:18:46.181: E/AndroidRuntime(7547):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
02-24 14:18:46.181: E/AndroidRuntime(7547):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6743)
02-24 14:18:46.181: E/AndroidRuntime(7547):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:352)
02-24 14:18:46.181: E/AndroidRuntime(7547):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1640)
02-24 14:18:46.181: E/AndroidRuntime(7547):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
02-24 14:18:46.181: E/AndroidRuntime(7547):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1638)
02-24 14:18:46.181: E/AndroidRuntime(7547):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
02-24 14:18:46.181: E/AndroidRuntime(7547):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6743)
02-24 14:18:46.181: E/AndroidRuntime(7547):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:352)
02-24 14:18:46.181: E/AndroidRuntime(7547):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:1847)
02-24 14:18:46.181: E/AndroidRuntime(7547):     at android.view.ViewRoot.draw(ViewRoot.java:1407)
02-24 14:18:46.181: E/AndroidRuntime(7547):     at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1163)
02-24 14:18:46.181: E/AndroidRuntime(7547):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1727)
02-24 14:18:46.181: E/AndroidRuntime(7547):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-24 14:18:46.181: E/AndroidRuntime(7547):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-24 14:18:46.181: E/AndroidRuntime(7547):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
02-24 14:18:46.181: E/AndroidRuntime(7547):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-24 14:18:46.181: E/AndroidRuntime(7547):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
02-24 14:18:46.181: E/AndroidRuntime(7547):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
02-24 14:18:46.181: E/AndroidRuntime(7547):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
02-24 14:18:46.181: E/AndroidRuntime(7547):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**Code:**

```
package com.TestFace.FaceDetect;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;

import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.media.FaceDetector;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.TestFace.FaceDetect.Util.ColorBall;
import com.TestFace.FaceDetect.Util.FinalImageUploader;
import com.TestFace.FaceDetect.Util.FinalJSONParser;
import com.TestFace.FaceDetect.Util.ResultPack;

public class ProcessImage extends Activity{
    LinearLayout image;
    Handler errorHandler;
      Typeface face;
      private File pic;
      Handler responseHandler;
      Bitmap scaledImage;
      Handler startThreadHandler;
      Thread statusCheckerTH;
      TextView title;
      FinalImageUploader uploader;
      Thread uploaderTH;
      int responseCode;
      //ResultPack result = ResultPack.getSingletonObject();
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.process_image);

        image = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearLayout1);

        Bitmap img = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(getIntent().getExtras().getString("PATH"));
        //image.setImageBitmap(img);
        this.uploader = new FinalImageUploader();
        if (img == null)
          finish();
        scaledImage = scaleImage(img);

        if(scaledImage!=null)
        {
            pic = new File(getIntent().getExtras().getString("PATH"));
            try {
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pic.getPath());
                scaledImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 95, fos);
                fos.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        final ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(ProcessImage.this, "FaceDetection       ", "Loading....   ", true);

        final Handler handler = new Handler() {

           public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

               //   System.out.println("The id after Save:"+id.get(0).toString());
                   dialog.dismiss();
                  if(responseCode==0)
                  {
                     // setContentView(new MyView(ProcessImage.this));
                      //Toast.makeText(ProcessImage.this, "Face is not dedected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                      showDialog("Error", "Face not Dedected");
                  }
                  else
                  {
                     // dialog.dismiss();
                      finish();
                      //setContentView(new DrawView(ProcessImage.this));
                      Intent intent = new Intent(ProcessImage.this,REsultedImage.class);
                      startActivity(intent);
                      Toast.makeText(ProcessImage.this, "Hurray Face is dedected!!!!!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  }
              }
           };

           final Thread checkUpdate = new Thread() {

               public void run() {
                   try
                {
                       //setCameraDisplayOrientation(ProcessImage.this, cameraId, camera);
                  String responseString = uploader.uploadPicandSendRequest(new File(pic.getPath()));
                  System.out.println("the REsponse String=====================================>"+responseString);
                  FinalJSONParser parser = new FinalJSONParser(responseString);
                  responseCode = parser.getData();
                  if(responseCode==0)
                  {
                     /* dialog.dismiss();
                      Toast.makeText(ProcessImage.this, "Face is not dedected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();*/
                    handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
                  }
                  else
                  {
                    //Toast.makeText(ProcessImage.this, "Hurray Face is dedected!!!!!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    //image.addView(new MyView(ProcessImage.this));
                    handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
                  }
                 /* Message localMessage1 = new Message();
                  localMessage1.obj = localObject;
                  ProcessImage.this.responseHandler.sendMessage(localMessage1);*/
                  //return;
                }
                catch (ClientProtocolException localClientProtocolException)
                {
                  while (true)
                  {
                   /* Object localObject = new Message();
                    ((Message)localObject).obj = "Connection Error!";
                    ProcessImage.this.errorHandler.sendMessage((Message)localObject);*/
                    localClientProtocolException.printStackTrace();
                  }
                }
                catch (IOException localIOException)
                {
                  while (true)
                  {
                    /*Message localMessage2 = new Message();
                    localMessage2.obj = "Connection Error!";
                    ProcessImage.this.errorHandler.sendMessage(localMessage2);*/
                    localIOException.printStackTrace();
                  }
                }
                catch (Exception localException)
                {

                    localException.printStackTrace();

                }
                   handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
               }

           };
           checkUpdate.start();


        /*ProcessImage.this.uploaderTH.start();
         this.responseHandler = new Handler()
            {
              public void handleMessage(Message paramMessage)
              {

                  System.out.println("Message==========================================>"+paramMessage);
              }
            };
            this.startThreadHandler = new Handler()
            {
              public void handleMessage(Message paramMessage)
              {
                ProcessImage.this.uploaderTH.start();
              }
            };
            this.errorHandler = new Handler()
            {
              public void handleMessage(Message paramMessage)
              {
                String str = (String)paramMessage.obj;
                ProcessImage.this.showDialog("Error!", str);
              }
            };

            this.uploaderTH = new Thread(new Runnable()
            {
              public void run()
              {
                try
                {
                  String responseString = uploader.uploadPicandSendRequest(ProcessImage.this.pic);
                  FinalJSONParser parser = new FinalJSONParser(responseString);
                  parser.getData();
                  Message localMessage1 = new Message();
                  localMessage1.obj = localObject;
                  ProcessImage.this.responseHandler.sendMessage(localMessage1);
                  //return;
                }
                catch (ClientProtocolException localClientProtocolException)
                {
                  while (true)
                  {
                    Object localObject = new Message();
                    ((Message)localObject).obj = "Connection Error!";
                    ProcessImage.this.errorHandler.sendMessage((Message)localObject);
                    localClientProtocolException.printStackTrace();
                  }
                }
                catch (IOException localIOException)
                {
                  while (true)
                  {
                    Message localMessage2 = new Message();
                    localMessage2.obj = "Connection Error!";
                    ProcessImage.this.errorHandler.sendMessage(localMessage2);
                    localIOException.printStackTrace();
                  }
                }
                catch (Exception localException)
                {
                  while (true)
                  {
                    Message localMessage2 = new Message();
                    localMessage2.obj = "Faces not found in your photo!";
                    ProcessImage.this.errorHandler.sendMessage(localMessage2);
                    localException.printStackTrace();
                  }
                }
              }
            }); */
    }

     private Bitmap scaleImage(Bitmap paramBitmap) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         int i = paramBitmap.getWidth();
         int j = paramBitmap.getHeight();
         System.out.println("The width:"+i);
         System.out.println("The Height:"+j);
         /*float f2 = j / i * 600;
         float f1 = 600 / i;
         f2 /= j;*/
         float scaleWidth = ((float)200)/i;
         float scaleHeight = ((float)200)/j;

         System.out.println("The value of f1 and f2:"+scaleWidth+" and "+scaleHeight);
         Matrix localMatrix = new Matrix();
         localMatrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
         return Bitmap.createBitmap(paramBitmap, 0, 0, i, j, localMatrix, true);
    }
    private void showDialog(String paramString1, String paramString2)
  {
    AlertDialog localAlertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
    localAlertDialog.setTitle(paramString1);
    localAlertDialog.setMessage(paramString2);
    localAlertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
    {
      public void onClick(DialogInterface paramDialogInterface, int paramInt)
      {
        paramDialogInterface.dismiss();
        ProcessImage.this.finish();
      }
    });
    localAlertDialog.show();
  }


}
```

**DrawView:**

```
package com.TestFace.FaceDetect;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;

import com.TestFace.FaceDetect.Util.ColorBall;
import com.TestFace.FaceDetect.Util.ResultPack;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.media.FaceDetector;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

public class DrawView extends View {
    private Bitmap myBitmap;
    private Bitmap myBitmap_Circle;
    private int width, height;
    private FaceDetector.Face[] detectedFaces;
    private int NUMBER_OF_FACES=1;
    private FaceDetector faceDetector;
    private int NUMBER_OF_FACE_DETECTED;
    private float eyeDistance;
    ResultPack result = ResultPack.getSingletonObject();
    private ColorBall[] colorballs = new ColorBall[3]; // array that holds the balls
    private int balID = 0; // variable to know what ball is being dragged
    //ResultPack result = new ResultPack();
    public DrawView(Context context) 
    {
        super(context);
         setFocusable(true); //necessary for getting the touch events

            // setting the start point for the balls
            Point point1 = new Point();
            point1.x = (int)result.getEyeLeftX()+50;
            point1.y = (int)result.getEyeLeftY()+25;
            Point point2 = new Point();
            point2.x = (int)result.getEyeRightX()+50;
            point2.y = (int)result.getEyeRightY()+25;
            Point point3 = new Point();
            point3.x = (int)result.getMouthCenterX()+50;
            point3.y = (int)result.getMouthCenterY()+25;

        BitmapFactory.Options bitmapFatoryOptions=new BitmapFactory.Options();
        bitmapFatoryOptions.inPreferredConfig=Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
        /*myBitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pic.getPath());
        myBitmap_Circle = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.circle);*/
        Drawable d=null;
        try {
            d = drawable_from_url(result.getImgUrl(), "Image Url");
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }  

        myBitmap=((BitmapDrawable)d).getBitmap();
        //myBitmap_Circle = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.circle);
         // declare each ball with the ColorBall class
        colorballs[0] = new ColorBall(context,myBitmap_Circle, point1);
        colorballs[1] = new ColorBall(context,myBitmap_Circle, point2);
        colorballs[2] = new ColorBall(context,myBitmap_Circle, point3);
        width=myBitmap.getWidth();
        height=myBitmap.getHeight();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        canvas.drawBitmap(myBitmap, 0,0, null);

        //draw the balls on the canvas
        for (ColorBall ball : colorballs) {
            canvas.drawBitmap(ball.getBitmap(), ball.getX(), ball.getY(), null);
          }
       /* canvas.drawCircle(result.getEyeRightX(), result.getEyeRightY(), 8, myPaint);
        canvas.drawCircle(result.getMouthCenterX(), result.getMouthCenterY(), 8, myPaint);*/
    }

     // events when touching the screen
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        int eventaction = event.getAction(); 

        int X = (int)event.getX(); 
        int Y = (int)event.getY(); 

        switch (eventaction ) { 

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: // touch down so check if the finger is on a ball
            balID = 0;
            for (ColorBall ball : colorballs) {
                // check if inside the bounds of the ball (circle)
                // get the center for the ball
                int centerX = ball.getX() + 25;
                int centerY = ball.getY() + 25;

                // calculate the radius from the touch to the center of the ball
                double radCircle  = Math.sqrt( (double) (((centerX-X)*(centerX-X)) + (centerY-Y)*(centerY-Y)));

                // if the radius is smaller then 23 (radius of a ball is 22), then it must be on the ball
                if (radCircle < 23){
                    balID = ball.getID();
                    break;
                }

              }

             break; 


        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:   // touch drag with the ball
            // move the balls the same as the finger
            if (balID > 0) {
                colorballs[balID-1].setX(X-25);
                colorballs[balID-1].setY(Y-25);
            }

            break; 

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: 
            // touch drop - just do things here after dropping

             break; 
        } 
        // redraw the canvas
        invalidate(); 
        return true; 

    }
    Drawable drawable_from_url(String url, String src_name) throws java.net.MalformedURLException, java.io.IOException 
    {
        return Drawable.createFromStream(((java.io.InputStream)new java.net.URL(url).getContent()), src_name);
    }

}
```

Comment: Your logcat says nothing about the null pointer...

Comment: Where is NullPointerException in stackTrace?

Comment: com.TestFace.FaceDetect some thing wrong here

Comment: Hey all, I am sorry for your inconvenience, actually logcat was wrongly pasted.

Answer (score 1):

myBitmap is null cause this.

Maybe you make DrawView not dynamic load but in layout.xml, so the bitmap was not initial.